# Generate Override method onCreateDialog in class A extends ArrayAdapter<Media>

Tags: android

I have a class A that extends ArrayAdapter like this:

```
public class A extends ArrayAdapter<Media>{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Media data[] = null;

public Media_adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Media[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MediaHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new MediaHolder();
        holder.item_listview = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_listview);

        row.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MediaHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Media media = data[position];
    holder.item_listview.setText(media.item_listview);

    return row;
}

static class MediaHolder
{
    TextView item_listview;
}

}
```

I want Generate Override method **onCreateDialog** but it is not in the list!!

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    //
}
```

Though I can override it in Activity!
Is there a solution to override this method?

Comment: beacuse it is `Activity` method, not `ArrayAdapter`